# How to make sure a string is in the correct format

Tags: python, string, list

I need to make sure the inputed string is in the correct format. It must be in the format:
'#### #### #### ####' like a credit card number. How do I make sure my code will not accept something like '1234 5678 12345678' but accept '1234 5678 1234 5678'. I am not sure how to go about this. I have tried using the the len function, but that would accept anything with a len of 19, no matter how it is formatted. My guess is I would need to break it up into 4 strings and make sure they are all 4 characters long, but I don't know how to do that, or even if that is the correct way to go about it.

Comment: try regexp. It serves exactly this kind of tests.

Comment: This is probably one of the few cases where a ``regex`` is actually the right answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
s='1234 5678 1234 5678'

all([len(x) == 4 for x in s.split()])
True

s='1234 5678 12345678'
all([len(x) == 4 for x in s.split()])
False
```

To check all are also numeric:

```
s='1234 5678 1234 t578'
   all([len(x) == 4 and x.isdigit() for x in s.split()])
   False
```

Using `split`, splits the string at the whitespace.

So if `s = '1234 5678 1234 5678'`
using `list comprehension [x for x in s.split()]` where `x.split()` creates a list `['1234', '5678', '1234', '5578']`.

Checking `all([len(x) == 4 for x in s.split()])` makes sure all   elements  are four characters long and `x.isdigit()` makes sure they are numbers.

You could have an initial check like `if len(s.split())==4` as there have to be four elements in the list to match your needed input. So even if a user added input like `"1234 5678 1234"` you would catch that error also.

```
s='1234 5678 1234 5568'
if len(s.split())==4 and all([len(x) == 4 and x.isdigit() for x in s.split()]):
    print "all good"
all good
```

Comment: That doesn't check if they're actually numeric though. I.E. ``'ABCD EFGH IJKL MNOP'`` will also pass.

Comment: This is exactly what the OP is asking for.  "My guess is I would need to break it up into 4 strings and make sure they are all 4 characters long, but I don't know how to do that"

Comment: Great answer - regex are good but when you are trying to learn code they can get in the way because they are like an entire new language

Comment: @PyNEwbie, cheers, my thoughts exactly.

Answer (score 2):

Use regular expression:

```
import re
p=re.compile('[0-9]{4} [0-9]{4} [0-9]{4} [0-9]{4}')

p.match('1234 5678 1234 5678')
```

should return a match object, whereas 
`p.match('ABCD EFGH IJKL MNOP')` will return `None`

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `re` library (regex). There is a good starter [in this book](http://www.diveintopython3.net/regular-expressions.html) (as well as tons of other good stuff).

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(r'''
    ^          # match the beginning of the string
    (\d{4})    # match a group of 4 numbers and remember that group
    \D*        # optional separator of any number of non-digit characters
    (\d{4})    # match second group of 4 numbers
    \D*
    (\d{4})    # third group
    \D*
    (\d{4})    # fourth group
    $          # end of string
    ''', re.VERBOSE)

pattern.search(input_string).groups()    # returns the saved groups of 4 digits each in a list
pattern.match(input_string) is not None  # returns true or false (match or no match)
```

Note that this solution only matches four groups of four numbers each. This means that entries like `'1234 5678 1234 5678'` will get parsed into a list like `('1234', '5678', '1234', '5678')`, and so will entries like `'1234567812345678'`, or even `'1234 regex = cool 56781234 wewt regex 5678'`. There is some flexibility there. Note that the `^` at the beginning and the `$` at the end mean that the beginning of the string has to lie right before the first number group and the end must be right after the last one for it to match. You could make it more flexible by omitting these.

For an exact match on only what you want, try `pattern = re.compile(r'^(\d{4}) (\d{4}) (\d{4}) (\d{4})$')` instead.

And if you do not care about returning the numbers in a list, just whether the input string matches your format, then @caoy has it right, leave out the parenthesis (they store the match as a group), and use the `pattern.match(string)` command.

**EDIT:** udpated the verbose regex to include separators. Previously it failed if there were spaces or anything else between the groups of digits. Now the first pattern is very general, and the last pattern is very specific.

**EDIT 2:** added just checking whether a string matches the pattern.